# batchfile taskkill /IM cmd.exe not closing cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which moves a few files and starts a program and for some reason, after the batch file goes through all the commands in it, it doesn't close. The command prompt remains open on the screen, so I want to close it.

I tried typing the taskkill /IM cmd.exe as the last line of command at the end of the batch file but it still doesn't close cmd.exe, any idea why? It should close it right? 
Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off


mkdir C:\Windows\Temp

if exist "C:\Users\" goto win7

if exist "C:\Documents and Settings\" goto winxp

:win7
mkdir C:\folder1
xcopy /s /Y \\server1\Public C:\folder1
C:\folder1\application1

goto exit

:winxp
mkdir "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Organization\orgapp"
mkdir C:\folder1

xcopy /s /Y \\server1\Public C:\folder1
xcopy /s /Y C:\folder1\xp\application1  "C:\Documents and Settings\All    Users\Application Data\Organization\orgapp"

xcopy /s /Y C:\folder1\xp\application2 "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application    Data\Organization\orgapp"
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Organization\orgapp\application1"
goto exit

:exit
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```

Comment: Please post the batch file.

Comment: @Gabe, sure, I just posted the batch file.

Comment: Don't use something like `taskkill /IM cmd.exe` to exit from a script. You exit from a script with `exit /b`. With that said, does it help if you launch the applications via `start "C:\path\to\application"` instead of just `"C:\path\to\application"`?

Comment: Hm, adding the start and exit /b doesn't work, adding just start or adding just ext /b doesn't work either :/ Do you have any more suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
:exit
```

Comment: Does not work for me, I can not stop npm launched from cmd

Answer (score 2):

You need to "run as admin" to properly call taskkill

Answer (score 1):

Try `start "" "C:\folder1\application1"` in both places and remove the taskkill command (or replace it with `exit/b` if you need to). The extra double quotes are necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using:

:exit
exit

or calling another file which has:

exit /b which will terminate cmd.exe instead of just the script if it were in the same file.

i think "exit" will should work fine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what u trying to do... but if u wanna exit/close those batch file just used

```
:Exit
exit
```

if you wanna force close other's application try this commands

```
:Exit 
Taskkill /IM cmd.exe /f /t
```

Example: ( This just for education purpose only. )

```
@echo off`
. Press continue if you wanna close explorer.exe.
pause
Taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f /t
```

the function will kill task for explorer.exe

Comment: What does /T do?